# How do i compare dates from mongodb in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, express

I want to compare date that i fetch from mongodb and the one i provide while running the program(in node.js). Following is my mongodb schema.

```
    {
        date:{ type:Date },
        entry:{type:Date},
        late: {type: Boolean}

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do it in this way

```
time : { type : Date, default: Date.now }
```

hope this helps

Comment: Quick question when i fetch this time from mongodb how i am going to compare two dates the one from mongod and other that i provide. I mean i found they are different formats and i cant make them in same formats. If you could help to correct

Comment: Use moment.js for extracting time in desired format on both dates. You can have any desired format of date

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use momentjs to compare dates like this
var moment = require('moment');
var datetime = '2017-07-30T09:29:04.000Z';
var localTime = moment();
var oldTime = moment(datetime);
console.log("Current datetime is older than " + datetime + " by 10 days = " + 
(localTime.diff(oldTime, 'days') >= 10));
```

Comment: well i'm having issue with date that i fetched from mondodb. And can i use moment to compare dates from mongo and from node program

Comment: Yes you can use it to compare dates from nodejs program first install it using 
npm install moment